# Choosing between Lucid and Squeeze packages?

Tags: package-management, debian

When one has the possibility of choosing to install a given package either from a Debian Squeeze or Ubuntu Lucid repository on Ubuntu 12.04, which repository should one choose?

For example, WANDisco provides SVN1.7 packages for both Debian Squeeze and Ubuntu Lucid, but I need to install it on Ubuntu Precise. Which package should I go for?

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not much aware of the differences they may pocess, I hope there may not be much difference between them. I will suggest you to go with the Ubuntu Lucid repository on Ubuntu 12.04 than a Debian Squeeze one.